# Rank a column without using pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I have a table that looks like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.1 |
| 1 | 2.4 |
| 1 | 2.5 |
| 3 | 1.7 |
| 3 | 2.3 |
| 4 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 5.5 |

I am trying to rank column A using python 3. When a new number in column A is encountered, the rank resets to 1. This is what I want the resulting table to look like:

| A | B | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2.4 | 2 |
| 1 | 2.5 | 3 |
| 3 | 1.7 | 1 |
| 3 | 2.3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2.5 | 1 |
| 1 | 5.5 | 4 |

In Pandas I can do it like this:

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].rank(ascending=False)
```

But I want to do it without pandas.

Comment: Why is Postgres tagged? Can you do the ranking in sql with a window function like `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY B`?

Comment: That was a mistake, I'll remove that tag. I am trying to do this using python.

Comment: Where is your data stored? In a pandas DataFrame or what? Please provide a sample input and sample output (no images, but code)

Comment: The data is from a .xlsx file to be stored in a Postgres database -

Comment: If you just want to add an identifier which maintains a count of the prior records with the same Col A value, you could use a dict where the key = Col A value, and the value = count of records.  Every time you encounter a new value in col a, you add the dict[key] value to the new column and update the count in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished along the following lines:

```
def rankEnrties(table):
    d = dict():
    rank = []
    for item in table[A}:   # reading the entries in table column A
        cnt = d.pop(item, 1)
        rank.append(cnt)
        d[item] = cnt+1
    return rank
```

Comment: Interesting! Can this be done using list comprehension? I am new to python.

Comment: Given that you must keep track of the occurrences of multiple keys, I don't believe it would be possible, but I could easily be wrong about that.